# Ros Canopen PositionJointInterface working with mode 3?

Tags: ros, velocity

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I try to control my robot arm by ros canopen but the driver do not have Interpolated Position Mode which is mode 7.
I follow the canopen_test_utils example and it use mode 3 for position controller, but I got error as

```
[ERROR] [1516324623.132823131]: hardware_interface::PositionJointInterface cannot be provided in mode 3
[ERROR] [1516324623.132886958]: Could not switch controllers. The hardware interface combination for the requested controllers is unfeasible.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1516324623.133238] Failed to start controllers: joint_trajectory_pid_controller
```

So I just wonder can I use Profiled Velocity Mode for PositionJointInterface
?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280240/ros-canopen-positionjointinterface-working-with-mode-3?/) by [leo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33187/leo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-01-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [leo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33187/leo/) on 2018-01-18**:
Why my question is not showed on the question list and it says This post is awaiting moderation?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-01-18**:
I think the new users need to be approved as part of spam user prevention. Now you're approved :)

**Comment by [leo](https://answers.ros.org/users/33187/leo/) on 2018-01-18**:
Ok, I see, Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Profiled velocity mode does not offer `hardware_interface::PositionJointInterface`, but `hardware_interface::VelocityJointInterface`.

That's why you have to use `velocity_controllers/JointTrajectoryController` with proper PID settings.

---

Originally posted by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) with karma: 1596 on 2018-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0